# Magento 2 creating duplicate log files

Tags: log, magento2.2.4

I think this started happening after upgrading to Magento 2.2 EE.

In my var/log directory, I have 2 files that Magento has created that have duplicate content: `system.log` and `support_report.log`.

If my memory serves correctly, those two files have always existed, but lines written to `system.log` were generally more severe errors generated by core magento modules. Any less severe, or anything in my custom modules that used `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface->log->info()` would get written to `support_report.log`.

Has something changed in recent versions of Magento thats causing these duplicate logs? Is there a way to separate or stop logging to one of the files?

Or, more likely, is it a Magento bug?

Comment: I've been wondering this too. When `system.log` starts getting complainy, and I see tens of MB of log files in there... it's all duplicated into `support_report.log`. We currently ship _all_ the log files to an ElasticSearch cluster, and it's incredibly annoying to have to deal with this duplicate log file.

Answer (score 0):

**Magento_Support** module was the one which was creating `support_report.log` file similar to `system.log`

One should disable `Magento_Support` module

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Support
```

Duplication issue fixed in the Magento 2.3.2 Commerce.

[See 2.3.2 Release Notes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.2Commerce.html#logging)