# Difference between support_report.log VS system.log

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to know what is the difference between `support_report.log` and `system.log`

Both Logs are same in `var/log`

Comment: Related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235181/magento-2-creating-duplicate-log-files

Answer (score 1):

There is no major difference between `support_report.log` and `system.log`.
`support_report.log` is the file generated by `Magento_Support` module.

`Magento_Support` module comes only in Commerce edition.

`Magento_Support` module is used for generation of system reports, which provide detailed information about the system environment and Magento instance configuration.

To get rid off this disable a module

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Support
```

[Fixed in the Magento 2.3.2](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.2Commerce.html#logging)